# NoSuchMethod exception using google endpoints + JDO

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, jdo, google-cloud-endpoints

I am doing a basic JDO query to search for an user which worked well until yesterday, but know I am getting this internal exception without (aparently) changing nothing in my code.
It happens both on development and production server.

The simple query:

```
PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();

Query query = pm.newQuery(KomiUser.class);
query.setFilter("email == emailParam");
query.declareParameters("String emailParam");
List<KomiUser> results = (List<KomiUser>) query.execute(email);

if (results != null && results.size() > 0)
      return results.get(0); //should be only one

return null;
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
sep 03, 2014 11:00:15 AM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
Información: cause={0}
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor: method <init>()V not found
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.<init>(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:52)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQueryImpl.runQuery(PreparedQueryImpl.java:39)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQueryImpl.asQueryResultIterator(PreparedQueryImpl.java:69)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BasePreparedQuery$2.iterator(BasePreparedQuery.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BasePreparedQuery$2.iterator(BasePreparedQuery.java:42)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterable$1.get(RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterable.java:49)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterable$1.get(RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterable.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.QueryExceptionWrappers$1.get(QueryExceptionWrappers.java:49)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.QueryExceptionWrappers$2.get(QueryExceptionWrappers.java:68)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterable.iterator(RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterable.java:57)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.<init>(LazyResult.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult.<init>(StreamingQueryResult.java:67)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery.newStreamingQueryResultForEntities(DatastoreQuery.java:442)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery.wrapEntityQueryResult(DatastoreQuery.java:421)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery.performExecute(DatastoreQuery.java:343)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JDOQLQuery.performExecute(JDOQLQuery.java:164)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1789)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithArray(Query.java:1666)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:243)
    at com.meanwhile.komi.head.users.UserDataAccess.getUserByEmail(UserDataAccess.java:21)
    at com.meanwhile.komi.head.UserEndpoint.insertKomiUser(UserEndpoint.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.10'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.10'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.10'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.10'
    compile 'com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:2.1.2'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm:4.0'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:4.0b3'
    compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
    compile 'javax.jdo:jdo-api:3.0.1'
    compile 'javax.transaction:jta:1.1'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:3.1.3'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:3.1.3'

}
```

My User class:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class KomiUser {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String key;

    @Persistent
    private  String email;

    @Persistent
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.unindexed", value="true")
    private String img;

    @Persistent (defaultFetchGroup = "false", mappedBy = "user")
    @Order(extensions = @Extension(vendorName ="datanucleus", key = "list-ordering", value = "date desc"))
    private List<Review> reviews;

    ...
```

}

Thanks for the time

Comment: NoSuchMethodError means using inconsistent versions of jars, so some jar is out of step with the others

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @BillyFrost. I have added my build.gradle above. I tried to find any inconsistency but found nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I made this work by using the following dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
        appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.10'
        compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.10'
        compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.10'
        compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
        compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
        compile 'javax.jdo:jdo-api:3.0.1'
        compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:3.1.3'
        compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:3.1.3'
        compile 'com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:2.1.2'
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use newer version of all dependencies, you can find newest version at http://mvnrepository.com/

Then, keep watching on newest release and update your SDK and all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and i resolved it by changing the Objectify version from:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:4.0b3'
```

To:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.3'
```